# ZFS data being removed

Tags: zfs

I have a partition on a drive which holds my ZFS data, the issue i am facing is that when my system performs an update, the zpool is being mounted to the correct directory on reboot, however all 135 gigs of data is lost when there is nothing being done with the data while this takes place.

Comment: Are the datasets within that pool failing to remount? Unless there's something screwy in your system update, I see no reason why any of your data would be deleted. More likely, it is still there but inaccessible for some reason.

Comment: @Dan ZFS is being uninstalled and reinstalled during my update procedure, which im assuming is causing whatever pools were previously created to be removed. I have seen that the create command is being run post update on boot by zfs  by running ''zpool history'' command.

Comment: Reinstalling the ZFS kernel module should not cause any datasets to be deleted or pools to be recreated from scratch. If they really were deleted, I would absolutely complain to whoever wrote the upgrade script you’re using.